# How do I paste contents of one worksheet onto a new worksheet that gets its name from a specific cell in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have got this code that makes me a new worksheet where the name of the new worksheet is based off of the value in a worksheet named Questionnaire, "C1". After this new worksheet is made, I want to copy the contents from Questionnaire "A1:B16" and paste in this new worksheet "A1:B16". I will be doing this for lots of different new worksheet names so the final code will have to adapt to the new worksheet name each time.

```
function GenerateName() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();

sheet.insertSheet(newSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value from the cell "C1" of the sheet "Questionnaire", and want to insert new sheet with the retrieved value.
- You want to retrieve the values from "A1:B16" from the sheet "Questionnaire" to the inserted new sheet with the same range.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function GenerateName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Questionnaire");
  var newSheetName = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(newSheetName);
  sheet.getRange("A1:B16").copyTo(newSheet.getRange("A1"), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

- If you want to copy not only values but also the cell style, please modify `sheet.getRange("A1:B16").copyTo(newSheet.getRange("A1"), { contentsOnly: true });` to `sheet.getRange("A1:B16").copyTo(newSheet.getRange("A1"));`.

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly as I needed. I would never of figured this out

Comment: How would I go about just jumping to whichever Worksheet name was in C1?

Comment: @Hearno About your new question of `How would I go about just jumping to whichever Worksheet name was in C1?`, how about putting `sheet.getRange("C1").activate()` to the last line of the function?

Comment: I was wanting something that didn't make a new worksheet but still took me to whichever tab that has it's name in C1. I tried to take out the last two lines of the code that you provided earlier and substitute the line you just gave me in the comment, but it doesn't take me to the new page just to cell C1

Comment: @Hearno Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `just jumping to whichever Worksheet name was in C1`, I  understood that you wanted to jump to the cell the worksheet name of "C1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: sorry, but the 'Worksheet name' would be in C1 and then I would want to jump to whichever worksheet thats' name is in C1

Comment: @Hearno Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `I would want to jump to whichever worksheet thats' name is in C1`, I cannot understand what you want to do. Do you want to move to "C1" of the inserted new sheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239106/discussion-between-hearno-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Sheet to Another Spreadsheet

This actually works but could be greatly improved with a custom dialog.  I'm working on that right now.  It does allow one to chose between multiple files with the same name.  The dialog displays the name of the file and path for each file it finds allowing the user to select which one they wish to copy the local sheet to.

```
function getSpreadsheetByName() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const tssname = sh.getRange("C1").getValue();
  const files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(tssname);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      let path = getPath(file.getId());
      let r = ui.prompt(`Name: ${file.getName()}`, `Path: ${path}`, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      if (r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
        sh.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()));
        return;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert('No files found');
  }

}
```

**Appearance of current dialog:**

[image]

**Helper function to get file Path:**

```
function getPath(id) {
  try {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
    var pA = [];
    pA.push(file.getName());
    var folder = file.getParents();
    while (folder.hasNext()) {
      var f = folder.next();
      pA.push(f.getName());
      folder = f.getParents()
    }
    var r = pA.reverse().join(' / ');
  }
  catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
  return r;
}
```